# How can I do validation on multiple objects simultaneously and add it to partial views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am developing a form for a Parent entity that has a list of Child entities in it.

In Parent.cshtml I am rendering the children in a partial view with a foreeach:

```
@foreach (var child in Model.Children)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_Child", child);
}
```

In _Child.cshtml I use this code:

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Children"))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.ValidatedProperty, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.ValidatedProperty, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
}
```

When the form is posted back to the server I need to add validation to Child.ValidatedProperty.
The values in ValidatedProperty must be ordered ascending.
For a given Child entity, ValidatedProperty is invalid if any of the preceding Child entities has a higher value in ValidatedProperty, or if any of the following Child entities has a lower value.

When I try to implement this I come across the following problems:

When I try to validate in the controller action and use

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Parent.Children.Child[" + i + "].ValidatedProperty", "Please enter a value between " + prev + " and " + next);
```

The message is not appearing on the screen.

When I try to make a ValidationAttribute or use the IValidatableObject interface I am unable to access the preceding and following Child entities so I cannot do my validation from there.

My ValidationMessage html node has the following markup when I view the source:

```
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Children[533f90da-4c11-40ca-bb07-e3f6bcbd7260].ValidatedProperty"></span>
```

All advice is very welcome!
If I need to supply more info please tell me what you need to know.
Thanks!

P.S. This is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do, the real validation is a bit more complex than just checking for the right order.

EDIT:
It appears that the call to Html.BeginCollection is adding the Children[533f90da-4c11-40ca-bb07-e3f6bcbd7260] part to the name of the validation element. When I remove the BeginCollection statement it comes out as:

```
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="ValidatedProperty"></span>
```

Unfortunately I need the BeginCollection statement for other functionality of the page. Is there any way to make the validation message work with BeginCollection?

SOLVED:

When I used the EditorTemplate like teo van kot suggested I could remove the BeginCollectionItem statement and every Child is now prefixed with a number instead of a guid. Now my AddModelError statement is working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but I guess you broke your binding a bit with `Html.RenderPartial()` that's why when you add your error with `ModelState.AddModelError()` it doesn't appear.

What i suggest you to do is to use [**EditorTemplate**](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/extending-editor-templates-for-asp.net-mvc/) instead of `Html.RenderPartial()`.

You should create folder `EditorTemplates` in `Views\Shared` and there create Strongly typed View for your `Model.Children` property ***with the same name that your `Children` property type have***.

Basically, it will be the same View that now you have under `_Child` name.

Then change:

```
@foreach (var child in Model.Children)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_Child", child);
}
```

To:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Children)
```

**Note that you don't need to set your model `IEnumerable<YourType>` or `List<YourType>` because EditorTemplates works even if you pass collection.**

Now all binding will be fine. You can check it in a browser with **F12** key and inspect your `ValidatedProperty` `input` `name` attribute. Then you will be able to use your `ModelState.AddModelError()` method.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I haven't used the EditorTemplate so far. So when I

Comment: I used the EditorTemplate and now I am able to add the error message correctly. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Collections are evaluated based on index, but you need to reference the collection name inside your model. Based in ValidationMessage of your markup, the model state error must be:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Parent[" + i + "].ValidatedProperty", "Please enter a value between " + prev + " and " + next);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem was The BeginItemCollection statement with added a guid to every item. I used an EditorTemplate and now don't need the BeginItemCollection and I can indeed reference the item in the way you suggested.